# Loop through all products in one page web-site Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

There is a one-page website with products (like Amazon), I'm trying to get product name, price, and date of publishing. 
My code only shows the first product.

I'm using beautifulsoup libraries for python 3.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://tap.az/all/consumer-electronics/phones?p%5B749%5D=3860')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'products-i'})

records = []
for result in results:
    model = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'products-name'}).text
    price = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'price-val'}).text + ' AZN'
    date_and_place = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'products-created'}).text
    url = soup.find('a', attrs={'class': 'products-link'})   # NEED UPDATE! URGENT!

records.append((model, price, date_and_place))
print(records)
```

I expect all the products to be shown on the console.

Comment: indent `records.append((model, price, date_and_place))` so that it falls within the for loop

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh it returns me the same first product information but many times.

Comment: then the logic needs to be checked

Comment: You loop over the results, but never seem to use the `result` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were searching `r.text` (`soup.find(...)`) in the loop.

find_all returned you an array of `results`, so to get the data that you need you should search in `result` object (`result.find(...)`) in the `for result in results:` loop.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://tap.az/all/consumer-electronics/phones?p%5B749%5D=3860')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'products-i'})

records = []
for result in results:
    model = result.find('div', attrs={'class': 'products-name'}).text
    price = result.find('span', attrs={'class': 'price-val'}).text + ' AZN'
    date_and_place = result.find('div', attrs={'class': 'products-created'}).text
    url = result.find('a', attrs={'class': 'products-link'})   # NEED UPDATE! URGENT!

    records.append((model, price, date_and_place))
print(records)
```

Comment: Just one more question, it doesn't return me all the products, on a website its ~1500 items, but it returns me ~100.

Comment: check the following: 1) website might have lazy loading, that `requests` can't deal with 2) website might have other kinds of javascript modifying `find_all` selector 3)maybe the website has an API that you can directly query instead of downloading an entire website.